# Diagram is not perfectly positioned using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-arrows

I want to draw a diagram with the following codes. But when I put some conditions over some "node", it is either overlapped or not aligned properly. How can I fix that?

```
\documentclass[]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\usepackage{tkz-berge}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows,shapes.geometric,trees}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]

\node (k1) {$\underset{(1)} {STEP1}$};
\node (k2) [right=of k1] {$ \underset{(2)} STEP2$};
\node (k3) [right=of k2] {$\underset{(3)} STEP3$};
\node (a1) [below=of k1] {$\underset{(4)} STEP4$};
\node (a2) [below=of k2] {$\underset{(5)} STEP5$};
\node (a3) [below=of k3] {$\underset{(6)} STEP6$};

\node (b1) [below=of a1] {$\underset{(7)} STEP7$};

\node (b2) [below=of a2] {$\underset{(8)} STEP8$};
\node (b3) [below=of a3] {$\underset{(9)} STEP9$};

\draw[->]

(k1) edge node[above]{Proposition 4} (k2)
(k2) edge (k3)
(a1) edge (a2)
%(a2) edge (a3)
(b1) edge (b2)
(b2) edge (b3);

\draw[->]
(k1) edge (a1)
(a1) edge (b1)
(k2) edge node[right]{proposition 1} (a2)
(a2) edge node[left]{proposition 1}(b2)
(k3) edge (a3);


\draw[->,dotted,thick]
(a2) edge[bend left=60] node[left,sloped] {Theorem 6} (k2)
(b2) edge [bend right=70] node[right,sloped] {Theorem5} (k2)
(b3) edge[bend left] node[below,sloped] {Theorem 5} (b2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure I fully understand what you mean by putting condition over some node. But to start with the text labeling the arrows is to wide for the arrows. You can set the node spacing using `node distance`, which I set to `2cm` vertical and `4cm` horisontal. I also adjusted the bend and the labels for the dotted arrows. And set each line in a separate `\draw` just because I think it is more readable. To get the small numbering of the node centered under the text using `\underset`, the whole text must be in `{}`.

Then to the node conditions. You can label the nodes (text outside the node) using `label` as an argument. It is done in node `k2` (STEP2) and `a1` (STEP4). But here I am not sure this is what you mean.

```
\documentclass[]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\usepackage{tkz-berge}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows,shapes.geometric,trees}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,node distance=2cm and 4cm]
  \node (k1) {$\underset{(1)} {STEP1}$};
  \node (k2) [right=of k1,label=90:$A<B$] {$\underset{(2)} {STEP2}$};
  \node (k3) [right=of k2] {$\underset{(3)} {STEP3}$};
  \node (a1) [below=of k1,label=180:$A>B$] {$\underset{(4)} {STEP4}$};
  \node (a2) [below=of k2] {$\underset{(5)} {STEP5}$};
  \node (a3) [below=of k3] {$\underset{(6)} {STEP6}$};

  \node (b1) [below=of a1] {$\underset{(7)} {STEP7}$};

  \node (b2) [below=of a2] {$\underset{(8)} {STEP8}$};
  \node (b3) [below=of a3] {$\underset{(9)} {STEP9}$};

  \draw[->] (k1) edge node[above]{Proposition 4} (k2);
  \draw[->]  (k2) edge (k3);
  \draw[->]  (a1) edge (a2);
  % \draw[->]  (a2) edge (a3);
  \draw[->]  (b1) edge (b2);
  \draw[->]  (b2) edge (b3);

  \draw[->] (k1) edge (a1);
  \draw[->]  (a1) edge (b1);
  \draw[->]  (k2) edge node[right]{Proposition 1} (a2);
  \draw[->]  (a2) edge node[left]{Proposition 1}(b2);
  \draw[->]  (k3) edge (a3);

  \draw[->,dotted,thick] (a2) edge[bend left=60] node[left,sloped,anchor=south] {Theorem 6} (k2);
  \draw[->,dotted,thick] (b2) edge [bend right=70,looseness=1.4] node[right,sloped,anchor=north] {Theorem 5} (k2);
  \draw[->,dotted,thick] (b3) edge[bend left] node[below,sloped] {Theorem 5} (b2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: When I tried to recall labelled Theorem number using \ref{theorem number}, it shows an error. How to fix this?